# mysql count combination of non unique data in row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

i have table like

```
+---+----+
|TID|DATA|
+---+----+
|1  |C   |
+---+----+
|1  |F   |
+---+----+
|1  |D   |
+---+----+
|1  |E   |
+---+----+
|2  |X   |
+---+----+
|2  |C   |
+---+----+
|2  |B   |
+---+----+
|2  |F   |
+---+----+
|3  |C   |
+---+----+
```

i want to count frequency from combination of data C and F group by their tid

so the count result for data `C` and `F` would be like = 2. (appear on tid 1 and 2)

this is my query

```
select count(data) from tabel where data like '%C%' and '%F%' group by tid
```

it didn't return the desired result

is it possible to query the result like that in mysql? or i need to manipulating it in program first? (i'm using vb net)

'UPDATE REQUIREMENT

i want to create the combination dynamically. is it possible to do that? i want to use `while` to iterate through the `if statement`. but it didn't return any result and gave me an error

here's my code. it's still error and i think the cause is because i can't use `ALIAS COLUMN` on `IF CONDITIONAL`

```
select count(*) from (
select kode_faktur,


if `DATA` like '%F%' and '%B%' then 1
else 0
end if

AS freq

FROM `table`
GROUP BY tid
HAVING freq = 2
) t
```

and this is what i wanna do, iterating the `IF CONDITIONAL` through `WHILE`

```
select count(*) from (
select kode_faktur,

while i<x
if `DATA` like '%i%' then 1
else 0
end if

AS freq

FROM `table`
GROUP BY tid
HAVING freq = x
) t
```

and this one is original code from @Aziz Shaikh and this code worked

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT tid,
SUM(CASE 
   WHEN `data` LIKE '%C%' THEN 1 
   WHEN `data` LIKE '%F%' THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
   END
) AS freq
FROM `table`
GROUP BY tid
HAVING freq = 2
) t
```

personally i think this's to complicated in mysql. i choose to do this to saving my time instead of doing some code in program. the reason is because my program has already using too much connection and also proccessing big data. so i think mysql could be act like an alternative to my requirement

Comment: Your `C` appears on `tid=3` too, so why result is 2?

Comment: For the updated requirement, maybe stored procedures / cursors can be of some help.

Comment: hmm. how about i want to count the combination of `data`. With the condition: either one  of the data.

for example ` WHEN data LIKE %variable1% THEN 1 WHEN data LIKE variable 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0` if the variable 1 contains `C` but the variable 2 return empty value .. it will count the frequency only for `C`. but if both variable has value. it will count both frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
 SELECT tid,
   SUM(CASE 
       WHEN `data` LIKE '%C%' THEN 1 
       WHEN `data` LIKE '%F%' THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END
   ) AS freq
 FROM `table`
 GROUP BY tid
 HAVING freq = 2
) t
```

Comment: thx for the answer @Azis Shaiks. this is what i'm seeking for :)

Comment: @Azis Shaikh: may i ask another question, please? can i perform iteration inside `case syntax when` in mysql? so the requirement is like i want to find the combination of data with dynamic value. it's not always 2 data like ` C - F`. it could be more than 2 data. so what i think the syntax would be like ` FOR I TO X CASE WHEN 'data' like i then 1` ..... HAVING freq = x

Comment: i found out in dev.mysql that we can perform **iteration** in conditional syntax but not `CASE SYNTAX`. so, i change your code into using `IF STATEMENT` instead of `CASE SYNTAX`.but mysql gave me an error. i think the error is because i can't use alias for `IF STATEMENT`. i've updated my code in questions part. would you mind to take a look at it again, please? thx before

Answer (score 1):

You should use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
select count(data) from tabel where data like '%C%' OR '%F%' group by tid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM(SELECT tid, COUNT(DISTINCT a.data) cnt
     FROM tabel a 
     WHERE a.data IN ('C', 'F')
     GROUP BY tid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.data) = 2
   ) AS A
```